# Animate scrollTop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function when  on click it a `div` is being shown and that works fine. I have also tried to add animate `scrollTop` to the function where I would like to add `div` is shown & scroll to it. But unfortunately that's not working. I am not getting any errors in the console.

Here my code below:-

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#video-edit-button').click(function() {
        $('#video-edit-form').show();
        $('html,body').animate({
           scrollTop: $("#video-edit-form").offset().top
        });
      });
    });
```

```html
  <button class="btn btn-default button-edit" id="video-edit-button">Edit info</button>

    <div class="panel panel-default video-edit-form" id="video-edit-form">
         ....
    </div>
```

Comment: $(window).animate()  instead of body html maybe?

Comment: that is not working either

Comment: seems working for me https://plnkr.co/edit/QyLKIQEC8De2AMxrNVeI?p=preview , let me know in case you expecting something else.

Comment: Do you see a vertical scrollbar on your browser? If the content on your page does not overflow the browser window, no scroll will ever happen. Resize your window to a really small size, and test that way.

Comment: I had overflow:auto for my content, when I removed that it worked, thanks!

Comment: Check my answer, it's OK now

Answer (score 1):

That's what you're trying to implement?
https://plnkr.co/edit/0jVELqSpoUr4xxcarE0S?p=preview

### Here is the working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#video-edit-button').click(function() {
    $('#video-edit-form').fadeIn(1000);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#video-edit-form').offset().top }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.fakeContent {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.video-edit-form {
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fakeContent", style="background-color: black;">
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default video-edit-form" id="video-edit-form">
    Video Edit Form Here
  </div>

  <div class="fakeContent" style="background-color: green;">
  </div>
  <div class="fakeContent" style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div class="fakeContent" style="background-color: blue;">
  </div>
  <div class="fakeContent" style="background-color: yellow;">
  </div>
    
  <button class="btn btn-default button-edit" id="video-edit-button">Edit info</button>
</body>
```

### Cheers

Comment: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});`, besides it shouldn't scroll to the top of the document, but to the div in question

Comment: I have updated the answer and the plunker. Check it out

Comment: Is it OK now? You can place your video edit form everywhere you like in the DOM

Comment: good job :) I'd upvote for the time spend to help OP with usable example